# Building DTM using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, dem

I want to build a DTM.
I have extract the ground points from DSM raster by slope base methods and saved in to a raster.tif file.

Now I'm trying to extract ground points from raster.tif as GDAL dataset to use it in the GDAL grid and get my DTM.

But I get this error in using gdalxyz.py:

> 'gdal2xyz' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise with what you are doing?
As I understood, since You already have ground points.

1. Load Ground Points Vector.
2. Load DSM model.
3. Get elevation value from raster to points attributes.
4. Generate raster/TIN from this points using elevation value extracted above.
5. You will have your required DTM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run GDAL python scripts from within `OSGeo4WShell` running python with first parameter as path to py script and add script specific parameters behind:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.6>python "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.6\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal2xyz.py"
> ```
>
> usage: gdal2xyz.py [-h] [-skip] [-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize] [-b band [band ...]] [-allbands] [-csv] [-skipnodata]
> [-srcnodata [SRC_NODATA ...]] [-dstnodata [DST_NODATA ...]]
> src_dataset dst_dataset
> gdal2xyz.py: error: the following arguments are required: src_dataset, dst_dataset